# "null" value failing to serialize

Tags: java, json, jersey-client

I am using Jersey client to access rest service.

I am using `JSONObject` and setting a "null" literal in it. It fails while it is serialized.

Upon investigating, I found `JSONNull.equals()` method has this `"null".equals(value)` then it considers the value as `JSONNull` object.

And then, `JSONNull#isEmpty()` throws exceptions.

```
    net.sf.json.JSONObject params = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
    params.put("PGHIDENTIFIE", "null");
```

And when serialized it throws:

```
    Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Object is null (through reference chain: net.sf.json.JSONObject["PGHIDENTIFIE"]->net.sf.json.JSONNull["empty"])
```

How can I serialize that "null" value inside JSONObject? Thanks!

```
 DefaultClientConfig defaultClientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    defaultClientConfig.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);

    Client client = Client.create(defaultClientConfig);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(apiUrl);
    ClientResponse response =
                webResource.path(apiUrl).accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, params);
```

Comment: Plese [edit] your question and include the code that tries to serialize the  `params`.

Comment: Lutz, code is added.